# How to delete blank cells using formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I'm currently on the making on my sheet however I can't delete the blank cell automatically using formula.

I'm using this code

```
=IF($Z$1='Company List'!B1:B28,'Company List'!A1:A28,"")
```

This is the formula that I used in order to return the exact match/value. However what happens is that it do have blank cells in between which I don't need to use. Something like this:

```
Date:
9/1/2021
[blank cell]
[blank cell]
[blank cell]
[blank cell]
[blank cell]
[blank cell]
[blank cell]
9/12/2021
[blank cell]
[blank cell]
9/18/2021
9/18/2021
9/18/2021
9/28/2021
[blank cell]
[blank cell]
10/05/2021
```

The desired output is like this:

```
Date:
9/1/2021
9/12/2021
9/18/2021
9/18/2021
9/18/2021
9/28/2021
10/5/2021
```

What formula could I add inside my formula to disregard or delete blank cell have output just like in the desired one?

This will be very a great help!

[image: Sheet Screenshot]

Comment: Sort your data table by the date, so all blank rows are together and delete them in one fell swoop. Your table setup with the merged cells will make processing very difficult.

Comment: Hello, thank you for replying. Actually, its not about the date only, also the different random items. All the data was all in a one sheet, and I just need to get specific data according to what I'm looking for. Its like I have a company list, and from there, I need to separate them according to to their types. Thank you!

Comment: Technically you cannot delete/hide a row with a formula.  If you really want to delete it, a macro will take care of it or you can manually delete it as teylyn said but this is not the case.  What you can do is filtering your data in a seperate sheet and after filtering blank values, copy&paste your desired rows into your main sheet you want to use as a reporting template.  If this process is something recurring frequently, you can write a macro to save time.

Comment: Hello, thank you both so much for answering, but I think I found the best formula just to get my specific data that I need, and it turned out what I need just like my desired output. It may not be delete, but yeah, I just did some changes on my formula. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this formula that I used to achieve the desired output indicated above.

```
=INDEX('Company List (2)'!A2:A26,SMALL(IF('Company List (2)'!B2:B26=B1,ROW('Company List (2)'!B2:B26)-1,""),ROW('Company List (2)'!B2:B26)-1))
```

Company list - this can be change depending the name of your sheet. Thank you!